# Pushing Offline Leads using Adwords API

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the below function to push my offline leads to api, everything looks good and returns success but when I check adwords, it doesnt show any data saying it received. I have tried many leads and also waited for around 3-4 days now.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function UploadOfflineConversionsExample(AdWordsUser $user, $conversionName,$gClId, $conversionTime, $conversionValue) 
{

  // Get the services, which loads the required classes.
 // $conversionTrackerService = $user->GetService('ConversionTrackerService', ADWORDS_VERSION);
  $offlineConversionService = $user->GetService('OfflineConversionFeedService',  ADWORDS_VERSION);

  // Associate offline conversions with the upload conversion we created.
  $feed = new OfflineConversionFeed();
  $feed->conversionName = $conversionName;
  $feed->conversionTime = $conversionTime;
  $feed->conversionValue = $conversionValue;
  $feed->googleClickId = $gClId;

  $offlineConversionOperation = new OfflineConversionFeedOperation();
  $offlineConversionOperation->operator = 'ADD';
  $offlineConversionOperation->operand = $feed;

  $offlineConversionOperations = array($offlineConversionOperation);
  $result = $offlineConversionService->mutate($offlineConversionOperations);

  $feed = $result->value[0];

  return ("Uploaded offline conversion value of ". $feed->conversionValue.
    " for Google Click ID = ". $feed->googleClickId." and Conversion Name " . $feed->conversionName);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In adwords reports this conversion will be shown in **Conversions** Column. and change the daterange to the date what you pushed as **$conversionTime**